Подключение платежной системы prodamus через python aiogram
Помогите подключить платежную систему Продамус, а именно написать функции аналогичные нижескинутым (Тут для Юкасса):
1 функция для создания платежа, остальные для его проверки.
    """
    Создание счета на оплату.

    :param amount: Сумма для оплаты.
    :param chat_id: Идентификатор чата для привязки платежа.
    :param description: Описание платежа.
    :return: Кортеж, содержащий URL подтверждения и идентификатор платежа.

    """
    idempotence_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    payment = Payment.create({
        "amount": {
        "value": amount,
        "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "payment_method_data": {
        "type": "bank_card"
        },
        "confirmation": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "return_url": "https://t.me/moroki_net_bot"
        },
        "capture": True,
        "metadata": {
             "chat_id": chat_id
        },
        "description": description
                                }, idempotence_key)

    confirmation_url = payment.confirmation.confirmation_url
    return confirmation_url, payment.id

def check_invoice(payment_id: str) -> dict | bool:
    """
    Проверка статуса счета.

    :param payment_id: Идентификатор платежа для проверки.
    :return: Метаданные платежа, если статус "succeeded", иначе False.

    """
    paymant = yookassa.Payment.find_one(payment_id)
    if paymant.status == "succeeded":
        return paymant.metadata
    else:
        return False

async def check_payment_status(bot: Bot, chat_id: int, payment_id: str, payment_message_id: str, markup = None, file_name: str = None) -> None:
    """
    Проверка статуса оплаты и уведомление пользователя.

    :param bot: Объект бота для отправки сообщений.
    :param chat_id: Идентификатор чата для отправки уведомлений.
    :param payment_id: Идентификатор платежа для проверки статуса.
    :param markup: Клавиатура для ответа (по умолчанию None).
    :param payment_message_id: Cообщение для удаления.
    :param file_name: Путь до отправляемого файла.
    :return: None

    """
    end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
    while datetime.now() < end_time:
        result = check_invoice(payment_id)
        if result:
            await bot.send_document(chat_id, document=FSInputFile(file_name), caption=" Оплата прошла успешно!", reply_markup=markup)
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "⚠️ Истекло время оплаты!")
    
    await chat_delete_message(bot, chat_id, payment_message_id)```


За это людям деньги платят, а вам бесплатно написать, я правильно ТЗ понял?

Я тоже ничего не понял. Это примерно как рассуждать о биосфере планеты Земля, видя переж собой только мухомор. Насколько внятно и понятно сформулирован вопрос, такие и ответы. Ждать ситуации когда попадётся товарищ из этой сферы, увидит этот вопрос, будет знать чем посоветовать можно очень долго и очень нудно. Вероятность этого, мягко говоря, стремится к нулю.

В ходе долгих раздумий мне удалось решить эту проблему. При запуске бота мы также запускаем aiohttp сервер. Он будет доступен по адресу: http://<ваш публичный ip>:5000/webhook
Этот адрес кидаем в настройки продамуса (вебхук)
Затем запускаем код и кайфуем.

В ходе долгих раздумий мне удалось решить эту проблему. При запуске бота мы также запускаем aiohttp сервер. Он будет доступен по адресу: http://<ваш публичный ip>:5000/webhook
Этот адрес кидаем в настройки продамуса (вебхук)
Затем запускаем код и кайфуем.
```def generate_payment_link(data, secret_key = 'f0c4e402c129f6a0958a20ba2e7b4efcb429fba2be2c74feb7fc9cfa03c1621c', base_url="https://testwork2.payform.ru/"):
    """
    Генерирует ссылку для оплаты с указанными параметрами.

    :param data: Словарь с параметрами для запроса.
    :param secret_key: Секретный ключ для безопасности (если требуется).
    :param base_url: Базовый URL, по умолчанию 'https://testwork2.payform.ru/'.
    :return: Сформированная ссылка для оплаты.

    """
    data['secret_key'] = secret_key
    
    payment_link = base_url + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
    
    return payment_link```

```import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import FSInputFile
from tokens import BOT_TOKEN  # Ваш токен для бота
from handlers import router

# Асинхронный обработчик вебхука
async def webhook(request):
    try:
        # Получаем данные в формате x-www-form-urlencoded
        data = await request.post()

        # Извлекаем tg_user_id и products[0][name]
        tg_user_id = data.get('tg_user_id')
        product_name = data.get('products[0][name]')

        # Печатаем полученные данные для отладки
        print(f"Получены данные: tg_user_id = {tg_user_id}, product_name = {product_name}")

        # Проверяем, получены ли данные
        if not tg_user_id or not product_name:
            return web.Response(text="Не все необходимые данные присутствуют", status=400)

        # Пример отправки файла пользователю
        await send_file_to_user(tg_user_id, product_name)

        return web.Response(text="Файл успешно отправлен!", status=200)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка при обработке данных:", e)
        return web.Response(text="Ошибка обработки данных", status=400)

# Функция для отправки файла пользователю
async def send_file_to_user(tg_user_id, product_name):
    # Создаём объект бота
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
    async with bot:
        file_path = f'file/{product_name}.pdf'  # Здесь предполагается, что файл существует в каталоге 'files'

        try:
            # Отправляем файл пользователю
            await bot.send_document(
                tg_user_id, 
                FSInputFile(file_path), 
                caption=f"Файл для товара: {product_name}"
            )
            print(f"Файл {product_name}.pdf отправлен пользователю {tg_user_id}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при отправке файла пользователю {tg_user_id}: {e}")

# Функция для запуска aiohttp сервера
async def start_aiohttp():
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_post('/webhook', webhook)
    
    # Запуск веб-сервера на порту 5000
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, '0.0.0.0', 5000)
    await site.start()
    print("Сервер aiohttp запущен на порту 5000")

# Основная функция для запуска бота
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    print(f"Бот с токеном: {BOT_TOKEN}")
    # Запускаем бота в асинхронном режиме
    dp.include_router(router)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

# Запуск Flask и aiohttp в отдельных потоках
async def start_services():
    # Запуск сервера aiohttp
    await start_aiohttp()

    # Запуск бота
    await main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print('Бот и сервер aiohttp запущены!')
        asyncio.run(start_services())  # Запуск всех асинхронных сервисов
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Бот выключен!')```


Это сейчас нейросети такой код пишут? Или человек настолько странно код пишет
